# Eclipse's TPTP on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, profiling, eclipse-tptp

On the **Eclipse TPTP** web site, there are instructions on how to install this profiler. Here they are: http://eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/4.7.0/documents/installguide/InstallGuide.html

But the Agent that is required for the tool is **only available** for **Linux** and **Windows**. I run Eclipse on a Mac. Here are my questions:

1. Is there an **OSX distribution**?
2. Is there a **build-from-source** way to do it?
3. Is this agent mandatory? Can't TPTP **connect directly to the JVM** as JProfiler does?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Eclipse TPTP is no longer being developed [see here](https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm). The last release was Feb 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by greg-449, TPTP is now **shelved**. A lot of people have reported that TPTP is not working on OSX, and based on this, it's not planned to be fixed in the future.

https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm

As for me I have purchased a license for [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).